# xcode5 ios7 error compiling code

Tags: iphone, ios, macos

I am using xcode5 and ios7 and the compiler shows me this error:
Implicit conversion loses integer precision long long to NSInteger

```
     if (statusCode == 200 && !upload) {
    totalBytesExpectedToRead = [response expectedContentLength];
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLResponse expectedContentLength` returns type `long long`.

I suspect you have declared your `totalBytesExpectedToRead` variable as an `NSInteger`, if you make it `long long` the error will go away.

```
long long totalBytesExpectedToRead;
```

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong variable name. You are meant to replace the declaration of totalBytesExpectedToRead